# javascript fucntions are not automatically filiing textboxs having prices

Tags: javascript, html

```
 if (document.getElementById("event-type").innerHTML === "Fashionshoot") 
    {  document.getElementById("act_price").innerHTML="50000";      document.getElementById("adv_price").innerHTML=cal(document.getElementById("act_price").innerHTML);          
    } } 
function cal(actual)
 {  advance=(actual)*20/100;
    return advance; }
```

whereaas html code is

```
<TD VALIGn="TOP"><select name="event_type" class="textfield" id="event-type" onChange="price()">
```

Comment: Do you have an extra `}` in there?

Comment: If you format your code properly (line breaks, indentation) your code will be much more readable. Not only to you but also to those who you ask for help. It's a win-win situation. You also should ensure that your example here is **complete**. E.g. I don't see a definition for the `price` function. Maybe that's that issue? I can't tell because at this point I can't be sure whether you just made a mistake copying your code over or whether your code is really that broken.

Comment: there was mistake in coping the code...but price function works if i insert an alert box in it ...so i dont think so function defination is an issue ..

Comment: @sundi Then it is up to you to fix that mistake I assume.

Comment: @sundi: We can't help you if we are not able to reproduce the issue. I recommend to [learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) so that you can help yourself. Once you have identified the issue, you can ask a better defined question.

Answer (score 0):

In a select element you won't get selected text with `innerHTML`.
You must get selected value with `selectedIndex`
I fixed your function. You can use this script:

```
function price()
{
    var selectInput= document.getElementById("event-type");

    if (selectInput.options[selectInput.selectedIndex].text === "Fashionshoot") 
    { 
        document.getElementById("act_price").innerHTML="50000";
        document.getElementById("adv_price").innerHTML=cal(document.getElementById("act_price").innerHTML);          
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work.here act_price (actual price)and adv_price(advance price) are id's of 2 text boxes that should be automatically filled on basis of eventtype